# Travis CI: how to use repository variables in travis.yml

Tags: repository, environment-variables, yaml

I tried to use an enviromnet variable in my travis.yml, but all I get is an empty string. I have added a repository variable DEPLOY_KEY with some value to my repository settings, now I try to access it like this:

```
after_success:
  - "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json;' -X POST -d '{\"api-key\": $DEPLOY_KEY, \"branch\": $TRAVIS_BRANCH}' https://some.where/deploy"
```

I expected $DEPLOY_KEY to return my key, but instead it returns only an empty string, even though Travis does `export DEPLOY_KEY=[secure]` when running the build.
I think I need to add something like this to my travis.yml:

```
env:
  - secret: "..."
```

But my problem is, what is "..." exactly? Is it my repositories public key? I can't find any information on how to use repository variables inside my travis.yml in the docs.
Some solutions suggested that encrypted variables could be used instead, but then, why give me the ability to set repository variables in the first place?

Comment: any luck on this? same problem with repository variables

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/ shows how to use encrypted environment variables.

According to that document the "..." contains both the name of the environment variable and the value of the environment variable. You will need to to use the travis CLI tool to create that secret value. The command to generate that secret looks like `travis encrypt SOMEVAR="secretvalue"`

Comment: Thx, but I do not want use encrypted env vars, but rather repository vars. The docs confused me a little bit, so I thought I had to add `env` in my yml, but it turns out I can use $DEPLOY_KEY without defining it in my yml as expected. The correct curl call in after_success: `"curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json;' -X POST -d "{\\\"api-key\\\": \\\"$DEPLOY_KEY\\\", \\\"branch\\\": \\\"$TRAVIS_BRANCH\\\"}" https://some.where/deploy"`. Note the double quotes after -d and the double quotes with an escaped backslash. The JSON was bad formed, so my server interpreted it as null (embarrasing)